# What's a more efficient way to convert pandas dataframe to a bit map?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have a Pandas dataframe with 3 columns (**x, y, d**) and about **200, 000** rows. **x** and **y** are integers, denoting the position of the grid. **d** denotes point density of the grid. There are about **90** rows missing (not included in the df), all of which has a **d** of 0.

I want to plot the dataframe into a **501 * 501** pixel and each pixel's color is determined by its corresponding **d**.

I was able to do it using numpy, matplotlib, and PIL, the image looks like this: [gray scale heat map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWky5.png) However, the runtime is about **16s**. I wonder is there anyway to improve the performance?

The code is as following:

```
#read csv from HDFS to a pandas df 
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Read_CSV")
sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.csv("hdfs://localhost:9000/density/output/*", 
header=True, sep=",").toDF("x", "y", "d").toPandas()

def tuples(a): 
    return (a, a, a)

#lerps the density to a gray scale color
df['d'] = (df['d'] / 600 * 255).astype(int)
df['d'] = df['d'].apply(tuples)

#creates a 501 * 501 white image
img = Image.new( 'RGB', (501,501), "white")
pixels = img.load()

#goes through the df and colors the pixels
for i in range(len(df['x'])): 
    pixels[df['x'][i], df['y'][i]] = df['d'][i]
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, origin='lower', vmin=0, vmax=600)
```

The last step, iterating through the dataframe and coloring the pixels is the most time consuming (**~16s**), are there any alternatives that I can use? Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**
In my code, instead of using **[]** operator, I used **.at[]** for indexing the pandas dataframe. The runtime is improved by 100% (**~8s**). However, I would still love to know how to improve it further.

Comment: How about use an array for pixels : `pixels = np.zeros((501,501,3),dtype=np.uint8)`?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried to use the array for pixels but it didn't help with the runtime. I'm thinking that could it be accessing the pandas dataframe be too expensive?

Answer (score 1):

With `pixels` as the three-dim array, we could assign in a vectorized way -

```
pixels = np.zeros((501,501,3),dtype=np.uint8)
pixels[df['x'], df['y']] = np.vstack(df['d'].values)
```

Answer (score 1):

A pandas dataframe can be easily converted into an image using Pillow. Hope any of these syntaxes help you solve the problem

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('A.csv'), header=None)
dataframe.to_numpy()

# create Pillow image
image = Image.fromarray(dataframe, 'L')        # L is mode for grayscale
print(type(image))

# summarize image details
print(image.mode)
print(image.size)

#save image
img_filename = 'A.bmp'
image.save(img_filename)
print('saved:', img_filename)
```